# pygtk textview tab width?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

Is there a way to set the tab width of the pygtk TextView widget to be something other than 8spaces?

Right now I tried `textview.set_tabs(pango.TabArray(4, False))` However, it seems like I misunderstood the docs. What the actual way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

See the [docs](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-pangotabarray.html) for `pango.TabArray`: your statement `pango.Tabarray(4, False)` creates a tab array with four tab stops, all at position 0 points. What you want is this:

```
tabs = pango.TabArray(1, True)
tabs.set_tab(0, pango.TAB_LEFT, desired_tab_width)
textview.set_tab(tabs)
```

The value of `desired_tab_width` is not in spaces, however. See the function `set_tab_stops_internal()` in [this code from GtkSourceView](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtksourceview/tree/gtksourceview/gtksourceview.c) to see how they calculate the width of a space.